# How can I specify a header and the package of generated code?

Tags: scala, code-generation, isabelle

I'm generating Scala code with Isabelle. How can I specify a header for my Scala file? For example, I'd like to have something like this:

```
// Generated code. Generated with Isabelle/HOL
// File: blubb.thy line:1234
// Date: Wed, 27.03.2013
// exported code equations: bla blub blob ...
```

How can I specify the package to use? For example, to use the package `GENERATED`, the file should begin with the words `package GENERATED`.

---

The best idea I got so far is the `code_include` command with an empty second parameter (`""`).
If I choose a longer second parameter, the `Efficient_Nat` theory first emits its code. But I must write to the beginning of the file.

```
code_include Scala ""
{*package GENERATED

// Code generated by Isabelle
*}
```

How evil is this solution? If it is not that evil, how can I add things like the current date, the current thy file, and the line in which the `export_code` happens. Can I also add the code equations I exported but not their decencies?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`code_include` is the right thing for what you want. The second parameter identifies the includes and determines the order in which the code generator outputs different `code_include`s. As you have picked the empty identifier `""`, your text will always come first, but you cannot have multiple `code_include`s with the same identifier (the latter overwrites the former).

The text that you give to `code_include` inside `{*` and `*}` is not interpreted, so you cannot have dynamic parts there. However, if you use the ML interface of the code generator, you can generate the string just before invoking `export_code`. This might look as follows:

```
ML {*
val scala_header =
  let
    val package = "package GENERATED";   
    val date = Date.toString (Date.fromTimeLocal (Time.now ()))
    val header = package ^ "\n\n" ^ "// Generated by Isabelle on " ^ date ^ "\n"
  in
    Code_Target.add_include "Scala" ("", SOME (header, []))
  end
*}
```

Now, you just have to call `scala_header` before `export_code`:

```
setup {* scala_header *}
export_code ... in Scala file ...
```

This gives you roughly the correct generation date. In detail, the time will be the one when `setup {* scala_header *}` executes, which can be (due to multithreading) some time before `export_code` actually executes. Even in sequential mode, when you generate lots of code or do much preprocessing of the code equations, the gap may be several minutes.